# Jinja and Ansible - Extract Good groups to parse through

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to gather, dynamically, using jinja a list of "found" groups in our AD using GETENT module. It will cycle through various hosts and find host and "-group", if found, I just want the group returned.

Subsequently the data will be used elsewhere but pulling the data out is

Data:

```yaml
group_output:
  results:
  - ansible_facts:
      getent_group:
        host-sys@domain:
        - user01@domain,user02@domain
  - ansible_facts:
      getent_group:
        host-oradbs@domain:
  - ansible_facts:
      getent_group:
        host-webdev@domain:
  - ansible_facts:
      getent_group:
        host-docker@domain:
```

Code:

```yaml
{{ group_output.results |
   json_query('[].ansible_facts.getent_group') }}
```

Results:

```yaml
[{'host-sys@domain': ['user01@domain,user02@domain']},
 {'host-oradbas@domain': None},
 {'host-webdev@domain': None},
 {'host-docker@domain': None}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```yaml
  result: "{{ group_output.results|
              json_query('[].ansible_facts.getent_group.keys(@)')|
              flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - host-sys@domain
  - host-oradbs@domain
  - host-webdev@domain
  - host-docker@domain
```